# System uses 6GB out of 7

Tags: insider-preview, storage, nokia-lumia-735

I'm using Windows Phone 10 (with windows insider) and System occupies 6GB out of 7GB on my phone, leaving only 1GB free where I can barely fit some apps into. Additionally, if I have lower than 10MB free on my phone, apps don't work anymore - they just close shortly after I start them up.
By the way, only 'System' uses 6GB; not the temporary files or anything else.

Comment: What phone do you have? Which build are you using?

Comment: I have a Nokia Lumia 735 with os version 10.0.10166.0

Comment: Have you tried moving to a later build, such as 10581?

Comment: Have you tried hard resetting your phone after updating to Insider Preview?

Comment: Changing the build didnt help. I will do a complete reset and come back with a response

Comment: Okay so what's your question or problem?